Proof of Cauchy Integral formulas for the derivatives and taking differetiation under the integral sign.
I'm currently reviewing complex analysis, and reading two texts atm.
In Stein&Shakarchi, their proof of Corollary 4.2 is a quite straightforward computation. But they don't apply any lemma/theorem when taking the limit under the integral sign:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\int_C f(\xi)\frac{A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+\cdots+AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1}}{(\xi-z-h)(\xi-z)}d\xi=n\int_C \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi-z)^{n+1}}d\xi,$$
where $A:=1/(\xi-z-h)$ and $B:=1/(\xi-z)$.
However, in Freitag&Busam, where they prove the same result in their Theorem II.3.4 (Generalized Cauchy Integral Formula), they just state one line: "The proof follows by induction on $n$ with the help of II.3.2 and II.3.3". Now Theorem II.3.2 is the vanilla version of CIF for holomorphic functions. But Lemma II.3.3 is the so-called Leibniz rule, where they conclude on the validity of taking derivatives under the integral sign based on the assumption of the continuity of complex derivative $\frac{\partial f(t,z)}{\partial z}$ of the integrand.
Now my question is: if F&B Lemma II.3.3 relies on that continuity of the derivative assumption, how can it be applied in the proof of II.3.4, when that assumption is not given? I think, if I didn't remember wrong, the continuity of all the $n$th-derivatives is a consequence of the generalized CIF. Isn't that supposed to be the point?
Hope someone can clarify which result should come first and then be applied latter in the proof of another. A bit confused. Thanks in advance.
Update Silly me.
For Stein&Shakarchi proof, the integrand function, with $z$ fixed,
$$\eta(\xi,h):=f(\xi)\frac{A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+\cdots+AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1}}{(\xi-z-h)(\xi-z)}$$
is continuous on compact set $C\times \overline{\mathbb{D}_r(z)}$, where $\overline{\mathbb{D}_r(z)}\subset Int(C)$, and so is uniformly continuous. Then interchanging the integral sign with taking the limit $$\lim_{h\to0}\int_C \eta(\xi,h)d\xi =\int_C \lim_{h\to0}\eta(\xi,h)d\xi$$
is valid.
For Freitag&Busam, when applying II.3.3, it is not the continuity of $f'$ that is used, but that of
$$\left(\frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi -z)^{n+1}}\right)',$$
where $z$ is outside of function $f$. So no circular reasoning is involved.
